# last row of a queryset in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a query set in Django template. It has a price column. I want to display only the price of last row. Is there any template filter which will help the cause?

Comment: Have you ever read/checked the documents of django template?

Comment: did you try [last](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#last) from the django doc ?

Comment: I would have thought it would be more useful to split the last row out in your view and then just call the result in the template, that way your logic is taken care of before it hits the template.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those who suggust using filter {{ queryset | last }} are not right. You'll get 'Negative indexing is not supported' this way.

So, the only way seems writing custom filter or use an ugly construction like:

```
{% for obj in queryset %}
    {% if forloop.last %}
        {{ obj.price }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

UPD: According to Django changelog {{ queryset.last }} will work from 1.6

Comment: queryset.last gives the last item that matches your filters, **not** the last item in your selected set. forloop.last != queryset.last in 1.6. The former helped me out!

Comment: The correct way now is simply to call {{ queryset.last }}

Answer (score 3):

as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18978385/2478304 for Django 2.2 works

```
{{ order.first.id }}
{{ order.last.id }}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me `queryset.reverse()` and the `first` template filter did a good job to get the last entry of queryset:

```
   {{ objects.reverse.all|first }}
```